# Error Upgrading Blazor from 3.1 to 5.0 "does not have a property matching the name 'PreferExactMatches'"

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

As per the migration document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-templates) it recommends to add this property `PreferExactMatches`

[image]

When I do I get this error

`InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router' does not have a property matching the name 'PreferExactMatches'.`

Even the [API explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.routing.router?view=aspnetcore-5.0) says the property isn't there. Am I missing anything in here? Please suggest.
For now I am skipping it and its working.

Comment: Rebuild the solution

Comment: I did try 
`dotnet clean`
`dotnet nuget locals --clear all`
`dotnet restore`
`dotnet build`

in this order

Comment: and it's a runtime error that I get.

Comment: PreferExactMatches has been removed from Router tag I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MS migration document was in front of the patch release. (The document is edited in the meantime). The property PreferExactMatches is not yet released, but will be next days.

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/20838

Comment: That explains!  Thank you.

Comment: Update: It's updated and released. Update the runtime on the client and server to 5.0.1 or greater.

Comment: Updated (5.0.200-preview.20601.7) and still gives me that error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "PreferExactMatches" is something to do with 5.0.1 sdk patch.

SDK : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks

blog post :   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I am on sdk 5.0.1

```bash
dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.100
 Commit:    5044b93829

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.0
  Commit:  cf258a14b7

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.301 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```
Something else is missing

Comment: When I get stuck like this I close the project, manually delete the obj and bin folders from all the projects in the solution  and then open project again and rebuild 70% of the time this fixes things I cannot explain.

Answer (score 1):

PreferExactMatches="@true"

@ ! This is a typo by Microsoft.

Comment: Hey @robkuipers, welcome to SO. Could you kindly expand the answer a little more and add how you figured out it was a typo (your own experience or bug report in Github etc.) Cheers.

Comment: This is correct syntax. Changing this to a string will give you a runtime error.

Comment: But the error states: "...does not have a property matching the name 'PreferExactMatches'". So the change does nothing for this problem.

Comment: Actually both works for me. I have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

To anyone deploying to azure web apps, I believe I figured out the issue.

See yannik's post:

> The MS migration document was in front of the patch release. (The
> document is edited in the meantime). The property PreferExactMatches
> is not yet released, but will be next days.

Now notice that at time of writing (08Jan20) azure still only provides a preview version of .net 5.

[image: screenshot from azure (create web app)]

Hence, once azure web apps support the latest .net5 (5.0.1) this issue should be fixed.

Some alternatives:

- Deploy your web app using the Docker Container option (see img above)
- Publish a self-contained app.

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/deploy-run-container-app-service